# Auto increment inside template

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I've the below XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<uaeccc>
    <nd>
    <AN>-2-0001</AN>
        <h2>Ttle2</h2>
    </nd>
    <nd>
        <h1>Ttle1</h1>
        <h2>Ttle2</h2>
        <h3>Part 1 Contracts</h3>
        <h4>par2 sub contractts</h4>
    </nd>
    <nd>
        <h1>Ttle1</h1>
        <h2>Ttle2 </h2>
        <h3>Part 1 Contracts</h3>
        <h4>Part 2 Sub contracts</h4>
    </nd>
    <nd>
        <h1>Ttle1</h1>
        <h2>Ttle2 </h2>
        <h3>Part 1 Contracts</h3>
        <h4>part 2 sub contracts</h4>
    </nd>
</uaeccc>
```

Here i was trying to increment a number, but it is getting incremented only in that section.

Below is my XSLT.

```
<xsl:template match="uaeccc">
    <xsl:for-each select="nd">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="section" match="nd">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="./node()[1][self::page]" mode="first"/>
    <!-- Variables-->
    <xsl:variable name="getChap">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after((//AN)[1],'-'),'-')"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="count">
        <xsl:number level="any"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="classname">
        <!--Get name attribute of current node -->
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('section-sect','1')"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="Chn">
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number($getChap,'00')"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="chapternumber">
        <xsl:value-of select="$Chn"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="sectnum">
        <xsl:number level="any" count="section" format="1"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!--Create a string variable by concat string method  -->
    <xsl:variable name="sectionname">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('CH_',$chapternumber,'-SEC-', $count)"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- Template Content  -->
    <div class="{$classname}">
        <a name="{$sectionname}"> </a>
        <div class="section-title">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="h3"/>
        </div>
        <xsl:if test="./h4">
            <div class="{$classname}">
                <a name="{$sectionname}"> </a>
                <div class="section-title2">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="h4"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()[not(self::h4| self::h3)]"/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="AN"/>

<xsl:template match="h1"/>

<xsl:template match="h2"/>
```

My current output is

```
  <div class="section-sect1">
        <a name="CH_02-SEC-1"></a>
        <div class="section-title"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="section-sect1">
        <a name="CH_02-SEC-2"></a>
        <div class="section-title">
            <h3>Part 1 Contracts</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="section-sect1">
            <a name="CH_02-SEC-2"></a>
            <div class="section-title2">
                <h4>par2 sub contractts</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section-sect1">
        <a name="CH_02-SEC-3"></a>
        <div class="section-title">
            <h3>Part 1 Contracts</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="section-sect1">
            <a name="CH_02-SEC-3"></a>
            <div class="section-title2">
                <h4>Part 2 Sub contracts</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section-sect1">
        <a name="CH_02-SEC-4"></a>
        <div class="section-title">
            <h3>Part 1 Contracts</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="section-sect1">
            <a name="CH_02-SEC-4"></a>
            <div class="section-title2">
                <h4>part 2 sub contracts</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and expected output is

```
 <div class="section-sect1">
        <a name="CH_02-SEC-1"></a>
        <div class="section-title"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="section-sect1">
        <a name="CH_02-SEC-2"></a>
        <div class="section-title">
            <h3>Part 1 Contracts</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="section-sect1">
            <a name="CH_02-SEC-3"></a>
            <div class="section-title2">
                <h4>par2 sub contractts</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section-sect1">
        <a name="CH_02-SEC-4"></a>
        <div class="section-title">
            <h3>Part 1 Contracts</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="section-sect1">
            <a name="CH_02-SEC-5"></a>
            <div class="section-title2">
                <h4>Part 2 Sub contracts</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section-sect1">
        <a name="CH_02-SEC-6"></a>
        <div class="section-title">
            <h3>Part 1 Contracts</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="section-sect1">
            <a name="CH_02-SEC-7"></a>
            <div class="section-title2">
                <h4>part 2 sub contracts</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here i want to increment the number after `SEC-` every time there is `$classname`called.But here  in my XSLT, the increment occurs but is same in case of subsection also.

please let me know how can i get it fixed.

Here is a [Working Demo](http://xsltransform.net/jyH9rMF/1)

Comment: That' s quite unclear to know what you would do and count exactly. Actually `<xsl:number>` is "*counting*" relatively to the `<nd>` currently being processed so that you can't count the h1 h2 and so on. Please explain 1) how you would like your output document need to be organized (it looks like you want to perform some grouping) and 2) which elements the numbering must rely on (it seems you want to count h3 and h4). Thank you.

Comment: Hi @potame, Yes you are right. here initially, i started only by counting `<nd>`, later i came across where in if there is `h3` or `h4`, the count should be based on `h3` or `h4`.

Comment: And in the end,  you don't ouput `h1` and `h2` at all, do you?

Comment: Nop @potame, i don't output `h1` and `h2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't make heads or tails of your code. FWIW, the following stylesheet, when applied to your example input, will produce the required output (with the exception of wrapping the result in a single root element):

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/uaeccc">
    <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="nd">
    <div class="section-sect1">
        <xsl:variable name="sectionnum">
            <xsl:number count="nd|h4" level="any"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <a name="CH_02-SEC-{$sectionnum}"/>
        <div class="section-title">
            <xsl:copy-of select="h3"/>
        </div>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="h4"/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="h4">
    <div class="section-sect1">
        <xsl:variable name="sectionnum">
            <xsl:number count="nd|h4" level="any"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <a name="CH_02-SEC-{$sectionnum}"/>
        <div class="section-title2">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </div>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```